# DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch seems wrong

Tags: dart

From the [documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.3.0/dart-core/DateTime/DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch.html)

> The constructed DateTime represents 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z + millisecondsSinceEpoch ms in the given time zone (local or UTC).

Therefore, if my local timezone is +1, this test should pass -

```dart
test('DateTime', () {
  var dt = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(0, isUtc: true);
  expect(dt.toIso8601String(), '1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z');

  var dtLocal = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(0, isUtc: false);
  expect(dtLocal.toIso8601String(), '1970-01-01T00:00:00.000');
});
```

However, it fails as `dtLocal.toIso8601String()` gives `1970-01-01T01:00:00.000`. Is it just me or is the documentation unclear? I would expect it to just change the timezone, not the milliseconds since epoch based on the local timezone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The start of the epoch is 1970-01-01T00:00:00 **UTC**. The start of the the epoch is not different for different time zones. So the start of the epoch in *my* local time zone (EST/UTC-5) would be 5 hours before that date: 1969-12-31T19:00:00.

This is exactly what your code is trying to do. `dt` is getting the time of the epoch start in UTC+0. `dtLocal` is getting that exact same time, but putting it in your time zone, which appears to be UTC+1.

The behavior you're getting is expected.